# JQuery hide Class if other class is visible or shown

Tags: jquery, class, show-hide

Found similar questions but nothing that covers exactly what I need.  I kept it simple in my example and I want to use JQuery.

I have two classes.  I want to hide the "filter" div if the "category" div is shown on page load.  There are currently NO styles associated with either class. I believe I am pretty close but it doesn't work.

```
<script language="text/javascript">
if(!$(this).hasClass("category")){
$('filter').css('display', 'none');
}
</script>

<div class="category">By Category</div>
<div class="filter">By Custom Filter</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that your exact code? `this` isn't going to reference `.catagory` unless that code is in a handler of some sort.

Comment: Thanks so much guys, unfortunately I still cannot get it to function properly.  When I load the page I should NOT be able to see the "By Custom Filter" text..and I still do.  I must be missing something here.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you add jQuery to your site? The code would look something like: `<script src="/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`.

Comment: Yes I have added the full url https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js in the header.  I'm also placing the script in the header and the divs in the body.  Tried it in IE and FireFox still shows the text "By Custom Filter".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.length` to test if an element is present.

Use `.hide()` & `.show()` to show and hide elements.

And finally, you want the code to run only when the page has finished loading, so you want to wrap it all in `$(document).ready()`.

So something like this should work best:

```
<script language="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //following code will hide all elements with a class of 'filter'
        //if any elements with a class of 'category' are found
        if($('.category').length){
            $('.filter').hide();
        }
    });
</script>

<div class="category">By Category</div>
<div class="filter">By Custom Filter</div>
```

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: You have the right concept, exactly what I'm looking to accomplish, however I cannot get it to work.  Perhaps my JQuery link is bad: src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"?  Any ideas?

Comment: This has solved my issue thank you!  For some reason the JQuery i was linking to was not working.

Answer (score 2):

Change the selector to `$('.filter')`

Answer (score 2):

```
var $filter = $(".filter");
var $category = $(".category");

$category.is(":visible") ? $filter.hide() : $filter.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery**

```
$('div').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("category")) {
        $('.filter').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

**or just:**

```
if ($('.category').length) {
    $('.filter').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="category">By Category</div>
 <div class="filter">By Custom Filter</div>
```

Assuming by "shown on page load" you mean rendered and not the show/hide visibility.

```
$('.category').each(function(){
    $('.filter').hide();
});
```