# Hide class if another span's child class is visible using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

It's similar to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318391/jquery-hide-class-if-other-class-is-visible-or-shown) but not working.

Here my codes:

```
<span class="main_price">
   $50
</span>

<span class="option_price">
   <span class="option_price_value">
      $70
   </span>
</span>
```

By default "main_price" and "option_price" class is visible and "option_price_value" class is visible where has the options.

Now I'm trying to hide "main_price" when "option_price_value" is visible.

For more clear,
When has no options by default it's showing

```
<span class="main_price">
       $50
    </span>

    <span class="option_price">
    </span>
```

And when options available it should look like

```
<span class="main_price" style="display:none;">
       $50
    </span>

    <span class="option_price">
       <span class="option_price_value">
          $70
       </span>
    </span>
```

Comment: Please add your jQuery code you have tried

Comment: At a minimum, explain what event triggers the check. There is no "sniffer" for visibility. You have to do a check at some event or do a recurring loop.

Comment: I tried this,
<script language="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if($('.option_price_value').length){
            $('.main_price').hide();
        }
    });
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED to include jquery, my fiddle is working now. Check this new version out: https://jsfiddle.net/cbbs2oms/3/

Basically checking if there's any text in the option span and showing the main price only if there's not option value. Let me know if I've misunderstood.

```
$(".option_price_value").each(function(){
    if ($(this).text().trim().length) {
        $('.main_price').hide(); 
        console.log('has option');
    } else {
         $('.main_price').show(); 
         console.log('has no option');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but now it's showing both price. I need to hide .main_price and only show .option_price_value

Comment: edited the fiddle, forgot to choose the jquery selection on side. working now.https://jsfiddle.net/cbbs2oms/3/